missing /usr/share/gz directory
Ubuntu Noble + ROS2 + Harmonic  I installed gazebo using sudo apt-get install ros-jazzy-ros-gz (and it appeared to work) then I tried a YouTube tutorial and screwed things up (wrong gazebo version.) I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but  sudo debsums -s shows 100's of files missing. In fact the directory doesn't even exist. debsums: missing file /usr/share/gz/gz-harmonic/gazebodistro/collection-harmonic.yaml (from gz-harmonic package) How can I fix this?

the missing files were related to trying to install harmonic 2 different ways.
there are 2 ways to install gazebo harmonic sudo apt-get install ros-jazzy-ros-gz or by using sudo apt-get install gz-harmonic but they are not the same. ros-jazzy becomes part of ROS2 while gz-harmonic is a stand-alone install. the missing files I had were for gz-harmonic and when I uninstalled gz-harmonic sudo debsums -s found no missing files.
